# JMH Yields Inconsistent Results Between Forks

Tags: java, json, parsing, jmh

I am trying to benchmark the following JSON Java libraries to test their performance in each data type individually:

- jackson 2.13.1
- gson 2.9.0
- dsl-json 1.9.9

I have used this [issue](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/338) as a reference for prepping benchmarking environment. I have:

- turned off Turbo Boost
- turned off hyperthreading
- set a specific frequency

Environment specification:

```
Model: Dell XPS 13
Processor Name: i7-8565U
Number of Physical Cores: 4 (HT disabled)
Memory: 16 GB
Frequency: 1.7 GHz (dynamic scaling disabled)
```

JMH configuration:

```
# JMH version: 1.34
# VM version: JDK 11.0.14.1, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 11.0.14.1+1
# VM invoker: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.14.1+1/bin/java
# VM options: -Xms2g -Xmx5g
# Blackhole mode: full + dont-inline hint (auto-detected, use -Djmh.blackhole.autoDetect=false to disable)
# Warmup: 5 iterations, 10 s each
# Measurement: 10 iterations, 3 s each
# Timeout: 10 min per iteration
# Threads: 4 threads, will synchronize iterations
# Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
```

I benchmark each library with (randomly generated) payload of different sizes. (In this case, 1, 100 and 10000 in kilobytes.)

I see a run-to-run variance in the performance of some libraries. Some examples:

dsljson: deserialization of floats, 100kb:

```
# Fork: 1 of 2
# Warmup Iteration   1: 4029.774 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 3166.863 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 3159.217 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 3141.895 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 3133.101 ops/s
Iteration   1: 3167.981 ops/s
Iteration   2: 3125.062 ops/s
Iteration   3: 3117.676 ops/s
Iteration   4: 3111.584 ops/s
Iteration   5: 3166.126 ops/s
Iteration   6: 3115.660 ops/s
Iteration   7: 3174.774 ops/s
Iteration   8: 3145.705 ops/s
Iteration   9: 3114.003 ops/s
Iteration  10: 3110.038 ops/s

# Run progress: 30.00% complete, ETA 00:09:28
# Fork: 2 of 2
# Warmup Iteration   1: 4104.713 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 4835.940 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 4837.150 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 4843.004 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 4840.332 ops/s
Iteration   1: 4837.021 ops/s
Iteration   2: 4842.746 ops/s
Iteration   3: 4834.603 ops/s
Iteration   4: 4836.132 ops/s
Iteration   5: 4831.823 ops/s
Iteration   6: 4831.908 ops/s
Iteration   7: 4832.504 ops/s
Iteration   8: 4843.621 ops/s
Iteration   9: 4834.916 ops/s
Iteration  10: 4839.871 ops/s
```

dsljson: deserialization of booleans, 1kb:

```
# Fork: 1 of 2
# Warmup Iteration   1: 406004.866 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 271143.927 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 268366.029 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 274393.448 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 266508.634 ops/s
Iteration   1: 267538.158 ops/s
Iteration   2: 277851.756 ops/s
Iteration   3: 277347.214 ops/s
Iteration   4: 272775.976 ops/s
Iteration   5: 270001.148 ops/s
Iteration   6: 273953.473 ops/s
Iteration   7: 273338.470 ops/s
Iteration   8: 280372.852 ops/s
Iteration   9: 264382.761 ops/s
Iteration  10: 264932.107 ops/s

# Run progress: 10.00% complete, ETA 00:12:09
# Fork: 2 of 2
# Warmup Iteration   1: 958135.054 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   2: 1031335.205 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   3: 1034440.489 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   4: 1035388.796 ops/s
# Warmup Iteration   5: 1034207.076 ops/s
Iteration   1: 1033830.589 ops/s
Iteration   2: 1031242.576 ops/s
Iteration   3: 1033097.444 ops/s
Iteration   4: 1034703.830 ops/s
Iteration   5: 1033415.839 ops/s
Iteration   6: 1033738.399 ops/s
Iteration   7: 1032749.533 ops/s
Iteration   8: 1030372.684 ops/s
Iteration   9: 1033219.458 ops/s
Iteration  10: 1034653.749 ops/s
```

For more examples, please refer to the [repo](https://github.com/meylism/java-json-libraries-benchmark).

Could someone please guide me through the steps which can be taken to investigate this behaviour of the benchmark?